# How to unlock multiple luks-devices using dropbear-initramfs

Tags: debian, luks, initramfs, dmcrypt, dropbear

My system setup is as following:

1. One single SSD with LUKS and LVM (and of course an unencrypted `boot` partition). The debian system is installed there.
2. Two HDDs assembled as RAID0 with LUKS and LVM for some custom data

To unlock to LUKS-devices at boot time from remote, I tried to use dropbear-initramfs.

That works fine, to unlock the **first LUKS** device (on the SSD, with the debian system installed on):

1. I log in with ssh to dropbear/busybox
2. I use `cryptroot-unlock`, insert the key, and unlock it

But to unlock the **second LUKS** device (on the RAID0), I still needs some console.

Is there any way to unlock both LUKS devices together (or after another) using dropbear-initramfs / busybox? TIA!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Someone could say: RTFM ... `/usr/share/doc/cryptsetup/README.Debian.gz`, section 8.

The solution is to put **`initramfs`** to options in crypttab, like:

```
nvme0n1p3_crypt UUID=7988273-32b1-163b-8b44-e479f39f15a1 none luks,discard,initramfs
md_crypt        /dev/md/myraid                           none luks,discard,initramfs
```

Then `cryptroot-unlock` ask me to unlock **both LUKS** devices. :)

Comment: This worked well for me. I would add that the initrd needs to be updated following editing initramfs: `update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)`. I previously did this already and then updated `/etc/initramfs`, so I never re-ran `update-initramfs` and noticed this change did not work until I re-ran `update-initramfs`.